# a host of acting talent

Tags: meaning

*Iannucci’s film features **a host of acting talent** as the Russian dictator’s underlings, including Steve Buscemi, Jason Isaacs and Michael Palin.*

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/aug/11/the-death-of-stalin-first-trailer-armando-iannucci-steve-buscemi-jason-isaacs-michael-palin

I would like to ask why the noun "talent" is in singular. I understand the sentence that in the movie some actors which do not come from the same country as the director will appear and that these actors will play the roles of underlings. So I would wait "talents" (Steve Buscemi, Jason Isaacs and Michael Palin).

Comment: **Talent** there is the commodity, so to speak, not the (countable) synonym for "person with talent", a talent.

Comment: And "host" there doesn't mean "army" but "lotsa".  There's a whole lotta talent in that film. It's used as a quantifier.

Comment: *Talent* in the count sense @Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions, "person with talent", is mostly confined to discourse within the commercial-arts industry, and is by and large not well received by the people it designates: we prefer to be identified as  actors (or singers, or dancers, or whatever), not commodities.